# k-means/matplotlib　を使って、エネルギー消費量をクラスタリング。

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

matplotlibとk-meansを使用して、csvファイルをクラスタリングしようとしています。

私の扱っているcsvデータはエネルギー消費量に関するもので、以下のリンクのものとなります。
https://github.com/camenergydatalab/EnergyDataSimulationChallenge/blob/master/challenge2/data/total_watt.csv

一日ごとのエネルギー消費量を、低・中・高の三段階にクラスタリングしたいと考えています。
以下、コードとなります。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans



MY_FILE='total_watt.csv'
date = []
consumption = []


df = pd.read_csv(MY_FILE, parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
df = df.resample('1D', how='sum')


for row in df:
    if len(row) ==2 :
        date.append(row[0])
        consumption.append(row[1])


import datetime
for x in range(len(date)):
    date[x]=datetime.datetime.strptime(date[x], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

X = np.array([date, consumption])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print(centroids)
print(labels)

colors = ["b.","g.","r."]

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("coordinate:",X[i], "label:", labels[i])
    plt.plot(X[i][0], X[i][1], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)

plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0],centroids[:, 1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder = 10)

plt.show()
```

しかしこのコードを実行すると、以下のエラーメッセージが得られました。。

```
(DataVizProj)Soma-Suzuki:Soma Suzuki$ python 4.clusters.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4.clusters.py", line 31, in <module>
    kmeans.fit(X)
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 785, in fit
    X = self._check_fit_data(X)
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 755, in _check_fit_data
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=np.float64)
  File "/Users/Suzuki/Envs/DataVizProj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 367, in check_array
    % (n_features, shape_repr, ensure_min_features))
ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(2, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

どうすれば正しく、クラスタリングできるのでしょうか、。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下にコードを示しますが、特に解説を加えなくても理解していただけるかと思います。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import datetime

MY_FILE='total_watt.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(MY_FILE, header=None, names=('date', 'consumption'), parse_dates='date', index_col='date')
df = df.resample('1D', how='sum').dropna()

import matplotlib.dates as md
dates = md.date2num(df.index.to_pydatetime())
consumption = [v for vv in df.values for v in vv]

X = np.array(zip(dates, consumption))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print(centroids)
print(labels)

colors = ["b.", "g.", "r."]

ax = plt.gca()
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.xticks(rotation=25)

for i in range(len(dates)):
  print("coordinate:", dates[i], consumption[i], "label:", labels[i])
  plt.plot(dates[i], consumption[i], colors[labels[i]], markersize = 10)

plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], marker="x", s=150, linewidths=5, zorder=10)

plt.show()
```

[image: 出力結果]